How to draw an elipse in Flutter that takes as origin point the any corner of a rectable which is draw in
I have the fallowing code to draw ellipses:
enum OriginType { bottomLeft, bottomRight, topLeft, topRight, center }

class Background extends CustomPainter {
  final double screenWidth;
  final double screenHeight;

  Background({required this.screenWidth, required this.screenHeight});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    const double degToRad = 3.141592653589793238 / 180;

    canvas.drawRect(Offset.zero & size, Paint()..color = const Color(0xFFFFFFFF));

    void drawEllipse(double centerXPercent, double centerYPercent, double widthPercent, double heightPercent,
        Color color, double blurSigma, double rotateDegrees,
        {double opacity = 0.7, OriginType origin = OriginType.bottomRight}) {
      paint.color = color.withOpacity(opacity);
      double sigma = convertRadiusToSigma(blurSigma);
      paint.maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, sigma);

      // Convert centerX, centerY, width, and height percentages to actual pixel values
      double centerX = size.width * centerXPercent / 100;
      double centerY = size.height * centerYPercent / 100;
      double width = size.width * widthPercent / 100;
      double height = size.height * heightPercent / 100;

      canvas.save();
      // Calculate the translation offset based on the specified origin type
      Offset translateOffset;
      switch (origin) {
        case OriginType.bottomRight:
          translateOffset = Offset(centerX - width, centerY - height);
          break;
        case OriginType.bottomLeft:
          translateOffset = Offset(centerX, centerY - height);
          break;
        case OriginType.topRight:
          translateOffset = Offset(centerX - width, centerY);
          break;
        case OriginType.topLeft:
          translateOffset = Offset(centerX, centerY);
          break;
        case OriginType.center:
          translateOffset = Offset(centerX - width / 2, centerY - height / 2);
          break;
      }
      canvas.translate(translateOffset.dx, translateOffset.dy);

      // Rotate around the center of the ellipse if the origin is center; otherwise rotate around the bottom right if specified
      canvas.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
      canvas.rotate(rotateDegrees * degToRad);
      canvas.translate(-width / 2, -height / 2);

      // Draw the ellipse
      canvas.drawOval(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, width, height), paint);
      canvas.restore();
    }
    drawEllipse(50, 50, 60, 60, const Color(0xFFF00000), 0, 135, origin: OriginType.bottomRight);
}

depends on the shape of the ellipse sometimes like is not going to respect the origin points which should be the corners of the rectangle that should surround the ellipse.
Example:
drawEllipse(50, 50, 60, 60, const Color(0xFFF00000), 0, 135, origin: OriginType.bottomRight);

Is going to generate this image:

Instead the ellipse because it is centered on the middle of the screen with the origin point been the bottom right corner should be a bit more on the left.
Could anyone explain to me where the drawing is wrong?
Update:
Example of what is an origin point. In this image, it can be seen that the ellipse from a Figma design (set the X=0 and Y=0) has the origin point in the bottom right corner of the rectangle.


what you mean by "origin point" in terms of ellipse?

The origin point in the context of the ellipse specifies the reference corner or center for positioning and transformations.

@pskink I've also update the question to explain what I mean by origin point

drawEllipse(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, Size size, Offset translate, Alignment origin, double rotation) { final anchor = origin.alongSize(size); final matrix = composeMatrix( anchor: anchor, translate: translate, rotation: rotation, ); canvas ..save() ..transform(matrix.storage) ..drawOval(Offset.zero & size, paint) ..restore(); }

where composeMatrix is a handy method for matrix transformation (instead of bunch of canvas.rotate / canvas.translate etc): Matrix4 composeMatrix({ double scale = 1, double rotation = 0, Offset translate = Offset.zero, Offset anchor = Offset.zero, }) { final double c = cos(rotation) * scale; final double s = sin(rotation) * scale; final double dx = translate.dx - c * anchor.dx + s * anchor.dy; final double dy = translate.dy - s * anchor.dx - c * anchor.dy; return Matrix4(c, s, 0, 0, -s, c, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, dx, dy, 0, 1); }

I am not sure if this is supposed to be all the code but I've get your code and I have multiple problems with it.
1. I used the position of the X and Y not as an Offset but more as a percent. Because doing this depends on the screen size I will not have the same ellipse position
2. I have no option for color nor width or height of the ellipse
3. I am not entirely sure how the rotation parameter works, but when I do rotate my ellipse the whole shape of it is going to be changed, not only the rotation

4. I am not sure how the Alignment for the origin works, but when I try to change it with different options I will get weird positions every single time instead of the propper aligment
